# Docker support option is missing in Visual Studio for Mac 2019

Tags: docker, visual-studio-mac

Docker support option is missing in Visual Studio for Mac 2019 Version 8.3.11(build 1)

Version 8.3.11(build 1)

Comment: Do you mean "Add Docker Support" is missing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/docker-quickstart?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: Yes. I am unable to find it in the add option

Comment: If you read the comments of that linked article, you should see that you are not alone. Don't know what Microsoft has changed, but clearly that menu is not available now.